# Libgdx project crashes on android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So my LibGDX project works completely fine on desktop and on android too, but when I implement a float which measures the players score, the game will crash on android. The idea is that the score will decrease every time the screen is scrolled upwards and increase when it's scrolled downwards. I'm using gesturedetector controller for the scrolling. Here is the main code:

```
public class WorldScreen implements Screen{

private Texture bgCity;
private Texture bgLoop;
private Texture hud;

public static OrthographicCamera camera;
SpriteBatch batch;

Rectangle player;
Rectangle background;
Rectangle backgroundloop;

public float camx = 0;
public float camy = 0;

public static float score = 384400000;

GestureListenerC controller;

public WorldScreen(final JetpackGame aa) {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camx = camera.viewportWidth / 2f;
    camy = camera.viewportHeight / 2f;

    controller.update();
    camera.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(bgCity, background.x, background.y);
    if(background.y <= -3296){
        if(backgroundloop.y <= -800) backgroundloop.y = 0;
    }

    if(camy >= 100) batch.draw(bgLoop, backgroundloop.x, backgroundloop.y);
    if(camera.position.y >= 5360) camera.position.y = 4420;

    batch.end();        



}
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void show() {
    controller = new GestureListenerC();
    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(20, 0.5f, 2, 0.15f, controller);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gestureDetector);

    bgCity = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/city_BG.png"));
    bgLoop = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/loopBG.png"));
    hud = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/hud.png"));

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 420,800);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    player = new Rectangle();
    player.x = 420/2;
    player.y = 800/2;

    background = new Rectangle();
    background.x = 0;
    background.y = 0;
    background.width = 479;
    background.height = 4096;

    backgroundloop = new Rectangle();
    backgroundloop.x = 0;
    backgroundloop.y = 4096;
    backgroundloop.width = 512;
    backgroundloop.height = 1024;

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    bgCity.dispose();
    bgLoop.dispose();
    hud.dispose();
}

}
```

And here is the controller class:

```
public class GestureListenerC implements GestureListener{

public static float velX, velY;
public static boolean flinging = false;
float initialScale = 1;

public boolean touchDown (float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    flinging = false;
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean tap (float x, float y, int count, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean longPress (float x, float y) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean fling (float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
    flinging = true;
    velX = WorldScreen.camera.zoom * velocityX * 0.5f;
    velY = WorldScreen.camera.zoom * velocityY * 0.5f;
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pan (float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
    WorldScreen.camera.position.y += deltaY;
    WorldScreen.score -= deltaY;
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean panStop (float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean zoom (float originalDistance, float currentDistance) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pinch (Vector2 initialFirstPointer, Vector2 initialSecondPointer, Vector2 firstPointer, Vector2 secondPointer) {
    return false;
}

public void update () {
    if (flinging) {
        velY *= 0.98f;
        WorldScreen.score -= 0.2f * velY;
        WorldScreen.camera.position.add(0, velY * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 0);
        if (Math.abs(velY) < 0.01f) velY = 0;
    }
}
```

}

This is what logcat says:

```
    01-30 00:08:04.096  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
01-30 00:08:04.096  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority version is VE=SEPF_GT-N7105_4.4.2_0016
01-30 00:08:04.096  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
01-30 00:08:04.101  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-30 00:08:04.246  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.vahlaville.game.android-1/libgdx.so 0x4225e6d0
01-30 00:08:04.246  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.vahlaville.game.android-1/libgdx.so 0x4225e6d0
01-30 00:08:04.246  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.vahlaville.game.android-1/libgdx.so 0x4225e6d0, skipping init
01-30 00:08:04.246  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android W/dalvikvm﹕ No implementation found for native Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
01-30 00:08:04.251  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android E/ActivityThread﹕ Pause GC
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 00:08:04.281  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-30 00:08:04.301  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-30 00:08:04.316  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-30 00:08:04.321  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android E/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 23
    User space API version: 23
01-30 00:08:04.326  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android E/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Mar 21 13:52:50 KST 2014
01-30 00:08:04.386  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidInput﹕ sensor listener setup
01-30 00:08:04.456  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android E/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 23
    User space API version: 23
01-30 00:08:04.456  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android E/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Mar 21 13:52:50 KST 2014
01-30 00:08:04.521  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-30 00:08:04.546  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android W/GL2JNIView﹕ creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.vahlaville.game.android-1/libgdx.so 0x4225e6d0
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.vahlaville.game.android-1/libgdx.so' already loaded in same CL 0x4225e6d0
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/GL2﹕ all initialized 2
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ OGL renderer: Mali-400 MP
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ OGL vendor: ARM
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ OGL version: OpenGL ES 2.0
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ OGL extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth24 GL_ARM_rgba8 GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_ARM_mali_program_binary GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_robustness GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ framebuffer: (5, 6, 5, 0)
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ depthbuffer: (24)
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ stencilbuffer: (8)
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ samples: (0)
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ coverage sampling: (false)
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ Managed meshes/app: { }
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ Managed textures/app: { }
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ Managed shaders/app: { }
01-30 00:08:04.606  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ Managed buffers/app: { }
01-30 00:08:04.641  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 184K, 10% free 8392K/9312K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
01-30 00:08:04.641  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 9.494MB for 610323-byte allocation
01-30 00:08:04.656  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 8988K/9912K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
01-30 00:08:05.206  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4198dc08)
01-30 00:08:05.211  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 3970
    Process: com.vahlaville.game.android, PID: 17444
    com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: img/hud.png
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:130)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:121)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
            at com.vahlaville.game.screens.WorldScreen.show(WorldScreen.java:128)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
            at com.vahlaville.game.JetpackGame.create(JetpackGame.java:11)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:237)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
     Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: img/hud.png (Internal)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:77)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:130)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:121)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
            at com.vahlaville.game.screens.WorldScreen.show(WorldScreen.java:128)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
            at com.vahlaville.game.JetpackGame.create(JetpackGame.java:11)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:237)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: img/hud.png
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:316)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:290)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:75)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:130)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:121)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
            at com.vahlaville.game.screens.WorldScreen.show(WorldScreen.java:128)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
            at com.vahlaville.game.JetpackGame.create(JetpackGame.java:11)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:237)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
01-30 00:08:05.261  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidInput﹕ sensor listener tear down
01-30 00:08:05.261  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ Managed meshes/app: { }
01-30 00:08:05.261  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ Managed textures/app: { }
01-30 00:08:05.261  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ Managed shaders/app: { }
01-30 00:08:05.261  17444-17444/com.vahlaville.game.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ Managed buffers/app: { }
01-30 00:13:05.336  17444-17468/com.vahlaville.game.android I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 17444 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the cause of the problem but your logcat output says you have an error loading a resource:
`com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: img/hud.png`
I would check into that.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it helped, but try to review, this line:

`hud = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/hud.png"));`

> Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading
>   file: img/hud.png (Internal)

review, case sensitive, of the file name and  look that is a copy of the file, not a link.

Comment: Textures don't require Gdx.files.internal...

hud = new Texture("img/hud.png") would be enough

Answer (score 1):

what causing the problem is this line :

```
hud = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/hud.png"));
```

check if you have put the image file "hud.png" inside the img folder inside the **assets** folder resource in your Android Project

hope this will help !